# How do you group pandas dataframe rows based on permutation of booleans?

Tags: python, pandas, permutation

Imagine there is a pandas dataframe with five columns and n rows. Each column holds a boolean value.

Maths says there should be 32 permutations of boolean values.

How do I group them by the permutation of boolean values associated with each row so I can get a count on each group or return other properties?

For example, how do I find out how many rows associated with TTTTTs or TTTTFs or whatever permutation I'm interested in?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: You don't need to get the permutations. Just `groupby` and `count`, if there is no count, the result is 0. You can use a `defaultdict` for the output if you want.

Comment: How about you provide that dataframe instead of having us imagine it?

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks @MadPhysicist--I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @supposer. I added a couple more solutions for you to play with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. One way would be to just group by all the columns you care about at once. If you want the counts, you can call the `GroupBy.count` method on the result:

```
df.groupby(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']).count()
```

Or more simply, if all the columns are of interest:

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns)).count()
```

You could also convert the booleans to a number, and group on that:

```
df['Num'] = (df.to_numpy() << [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]).sum(0)
df.groupby('Num').count()
```

A more general solution that does not require creating a new column could use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
names = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']
pd.Series((df[names].to_numpy() << np.arange(len(names))).sum(0)).value_counts()
```

Which you can very conveniently rewrite as

```
pd.Series.value_counts((df[names].to_numpy() << np.arange(len(names))).sum(0))
```